# Automatically creates pivot table off of variable sized data set

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a macro that I use to create a pivot table off of order information for customers.  The size of the data is variable so I want the pivot table to automatically adjust the data source range based on the raw data table size.  I know you can have it create a named range and then automatically reference that named range but I can't get either to just select active cells.  How would I code this in VBA?  Here is the code I have so far:

```
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Parent Project Order Details!R1C1:R167C8", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
        :=6
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
        .ColumnGrand = True
        .HasAutoFormat = True
        .DisplayErrorString = False
        .DisplayNullString = True
        .EnableDrilldown = True
        .ErrorString = ""
        .MergeLabels = False
        .NullString = ""
        .PageFieldOrder = 2
        .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RowGrand = True
        .SaveData = True
        .PrintTitles = False
        .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
        .TotalsAnnotation = False
        .CompactRowIndent = 1
        .InGridDropZones = False
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
        .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
        .DisplayContextTooltips = True
        .ShowDrillIndicators = True
        .PrintDrillIndicators = False
        .AllowMultipleFilters = False
        .SortUsingCustomLists = True
        .FieldListSortAscending = False
        .ShowValuesRow = False
        .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
        .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("SKU Description")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Quantity"), "Sum of Quantity", xlSum
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Order Number")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
```

Tried using VBA to select the data but the pivot table needed a range that doesn't alway work for the orders

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is a blank column to the right of your data and a blank row below your data, you can use the currentRegion method of a range to dynamically get the contiguous data.  Just change:

```
 ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Parent Project Order Details!R1C1:R167C8", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
    :=6
```

to

```
 ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    range("Parent Project Order Details!R1C1").currentRegion, Version:=6).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
    :=6
```

It may also be a good idea to remove the argument that sets the table name because it may conflict.  If it missing, Excel will choose an appropriate name.  So just remove the following:

```
TableName:="PivotTable1",
```

I have a post on a blog that talks about other issues with using dynamic pivot tables at https://vba-course.blogspot.com/2021/12/working-with-pivot-tables.html

Comment: @allison, Welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer is helpful, you should mark it as the accepted answer.  If you are still struggling, feel free to ask a follow-up question in a comment